# How does the following codes of Lambda Expression execute?

Tags: kotlin, lambda, functional-programming, anonymous-function

I have created a customFilter for understanding Lambda Expression in Kotlin. The code is as follows;

I have understood how we can create our own custom filter function, how to pass lambda in a higher-order function but can't figure out the order in which the lines are getting executed.

```
    //Create a class extension function on List<Shape> called customFilter which takes a lambda function as argument
    //and returns a Boolean value. The class extension function returns a List
    fun List<Shape>.customFilter(filterFunction: (Shape, String) -> (Boolean)): List<Shape> {
        val resultList = mutableListOf<Shape>()
        for (shape in this) {
            if (filterFunction(shape)) {
                
                resultList.add(shape)
            }
        }
    
        return resultList
    }
     fun main(){
//assume all the following instances has been created.
     var shapes2 = listOf(circle1, circle2, triangle1, triangle2, rectangle1, rectangle2)
    
        shapes2 = shapes2.customFilter { shape, stringVar ->
            println(stringVar)
            shape.area() > 20
        }.sortedBy { item -> item.area() }
     
    }
```

In the following code according to which condition sum will be calculated?

```
fun main() {
    val list = (1..5).toList()

    val sum = list.customSum { item -> item % 2 == 0 }

    println(sum)
}

fun List<Int>.customSum(sumFunction: (Int) -> Boolean): Int {

    var sum = 0

    for (number in this) {
        if (number % 2 == 1)
            sum += number
    }
    return sum

}
```

Comment: Why don't you add print statements/use the debugger to find out for yourself?

Comment: I have added it and could not find any concept behind the pattern of output.

Comment: Your updated question has a problem - you never actually execute the lambda that you're passing into `customSum`. What you should be doing is something like:

`for (number in this) { if (someFunction(number)) { sum += number } }`

then return sum.

Comment: Maybe it would help to say this - a function is a first-class primitive in Kotlin. Meaning, it is a thing, you can pass around, and then use - even if you don't know the definition of the lambda yet. the key is they are typed (as in Types) based on the signature (e.g. `(Int) -> Boolean`) so Kotlin can then generate the appropriate generics / classes in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lambda is passed to your customFilter function, and that is when it is executed.

The order of operations, if you were to take the lambda-passing out of the picture might be something like this:

```kotlin
fun customFilteredList(shapes: List<Shape>): List<Shape> {
    val resultList = mutableListOf<Shape>()
    for (shape in shapes) {
        if (shape.area() > 20) {
            resultList.add(shape)
        }
    }
    return resultList
}

fun main() {
    // same instances from before
    val shapesBefore = listOf(circle1, circle2, triangle1, triangle2, rectangle1, rectangle2)
    val shapesAfter = customFilteredList(shapesBefore)
    // do more stuff
}
```

I hope the difference is clear. By defining any function that accepts a lambda (not just a filter), you are passing a reference to that entire lambda (a scope in its own right) to your function. Your function, then at that time, will execute the lambda within its own scope. All of this is executed within the scope of your `main()` call.

As an aside that may also help (it did for me) is that `filter` is a lambda-accepting function implemented in the kotlin standard library.

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val shapes = listOf(circle1, circle2, triangle1, triangle2, rectangle1, rectangle2).filter { shape ->
        shape.area() > 20
    }
}
```

I'm not sure where your `stringVar` is coming from, so I am not sure what you are expecting to happen with it in your function beyond printing it. It doesn't really make sense without more context as to why the string is needed when you are updating your list.

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful. stringVar I had added to add some print statement to understand the chronology of statement execution.

Comment: The explanation is really very cool, thank you.

Comment: Hey @tsalaroth, In following code according to which condition sum will be calculated? I have edited the main question with the following code.
fun main() {
    val list = (1..5).toList()

    val sum = list.customSum { item -> item % 2 == 0 }

    println(sum)
}

fun List<Int>.customSum(sumFunction: (Int) -> Boolean): Int {

    var sum = 0

    for (number in this) {
        if (number % 2 == 1)
            sum += number
    }
    return sum

}